# Export object as Excel File in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an angular js where I need to export an array of javascript objects. My code already has the provision to export is as a csv. To export as a csv the way is quite simple. I am building an object where each item is separated by a comma and each row by a new line and then using filewriter to write the file. For excel I came across an option like `Alasql`. Is there anyway I can do it? Is it possible to format the object in such a way so that we can directly use filewriter to save the object as an excel file?

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 ways to export your data in excel.

read here for more information [5-Ways-to-export](http://www.angularjs4u.com/modules/5-angularjs-microsoft-word-excel-integrations/)

And you can also use datatable plugin. 
https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html